# set post limit at load more ajax wordpress

Tags: php, posts, ajax

The site has load more posts functionality using ajax on vanilla javascript.

Ajax:

```
postData.append("action", "loadmore");
postData.append("paged", section_posts);
postData.append("posts_per_page", 9);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", ajaxurl);
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (data) {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        section_posts++;
        document.querySelector(".box").innerHTML += data.target.responseText;
    } else {}
});
xhr.send(postData);
```

This is code action ajax at `function.php`:

```
function loadmore_get_posts(){
  $paged = !empty($_POST['paged']) ? $_POST['paged'] : 1;
    $paged++;

 $args = array(
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST['posts_per_page'],
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
  );

    $data = new WP_Query( $args );
 
    while( $data->have_posts() ) : $data->the_post();
      get_template_part( 'templates/...' ); 
    endwhile;
  die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'loadmore_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'loadmore_get_posts');
```

This functionality works well! But I need to set a limit on the number of total posts.

For example: the total number of posts is **100**, but I need **50** posts to be loaded.

Pls, tell me how to solve my question. **I need to make a limit on the total number of posts**.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use a variable in JavaScript to keep track of the number of posts.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, do you mean something like `$paged * $_POST['posts_per_page']`?

Comment: No, in JavaScript…

Comment: @JacobPeattie, please show me an example. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Something v basic might look like this

```js
var ppp = 9;
var loaded = ppp;
var maxPosts = 50;
postData.append( 'action', 'loadmore' );
postData.append( 'paged', section_posts );
postData.append( 'posts_per_page', ppp );

if ( loaded < maxPosts ) { // check if we're below the max post number 
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'POST', ajaxurl );
    xhr.addEventListener( 'readystatechange', function ( data ) {
        if ( this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 ) {
            loaded = loaded + ppp; // Add our per page to our loaded tally
            section_posts++;
            document.querySelector( '.box' ).innerHTML +=
                data.target.responseText;
        } else {
        }
    } );
    xhr.send( postData );
} else {
    alert( 'You have loaded the maximum number of posts' );
}
```

It's not exact - it would still load `ppp` more posts if the `loaded` amount was 1 under for example. If you want to do something more you can put a secondary condition to check if you're below the limit but would be above with the added `ppp`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try a little later.

Comment: This does not work. Posts are no longer added at all.

Comment: Any console errors or anything else to go on here?? This is written freehand from chunks of code so there's not much to go on here

Comment: I've added a change to line 2 - just looking back. You'd want `loaded` to be initialised as a value